I can't get aliexpress meta tags using server functions
I’ve been stuck on an issue while trying to fetch metadata (like title, and images) from Aliexpress product URLs in my serverless functions hosted on Vercel. Here’s the weird part: it works perfectly in my local development environment, but returns blank strings when deployed to Vercel.
I’m using popular libraries like:

link-preview-js
unfurl.js

These libraries work great for most URLs, and on my local machine, they even return the correct metadata for Aliexpress links. However, once deployed to Vercel, the metadata response becomes incomplete or blank.
Here’s what I get when deployed on Vercel for an Aliexpress link (gets favicon only):
preview:  {
  url: 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005007613200043.html',
  title: '',
  siteName: undefined,
  description: undefined,
  mediaType: 'website',
  contentType: 'text/html',
  images: [],
  videos: [],
  favicons: [ 'https://www.aliexpress.com/favicon.ico' ],
  charset: 'UTF-8'
}


But locally, the response looks like this:
{
  "url": "https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1005007613200043.html",
  "title": "realme-Smartphone C61, Batterie 5000mAh, Charge SUPERVOOC 15W, Caméra AI 50MP...",
  "description": "Smarter Shopping, Better Living! Aliexpress.com",
  "images": [
    "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/S4f8e9c491b8c415387e2b3525570cce2R/realme-Smartphone-C61-Batterie-5000mAh-Charge-SUPERVOOC-15W-Cam-ra-AI.jpg"
  ],
  "siteName": "Aliexpress",
  ...
}


My function :
import type { VercelRequest, VercelResponse } from '@vercel/node'
import { getLinkPreview } from 'link-preview-js';

export const config = {
    regions: ['cdg1'],
  };
export default async function handler(req: VercelRequest, res: VercelResponse) {
  const url = 'https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1005007096221203.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2fra'
  const preview = await getLinkPreview(url, { followRedirects: "follow", 
    
  },
});
  return res.json({
    message: preview,
  })
}

I've tried to use convex functions but got the same result, So I feel it is a restriction from Aliexpress or a limitation by the packages.
What do you think? what's the best route to take from here?
